# Change material on click Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement

I am trying to change material rendered on a cube upon click. Simple if else condition (I believe). I have tried

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("Click");

             if (GetComponent<Renderer>().material == brick)
                {
                Debug.Log("Brick");
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material = normal;

                }
            else if(GetComponent<Renderer>().material == normal)
                {
                Debug.Log("Normal");
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material = brick;
            }
              
        }
    }
```

I am getting in the first loop ie `GetMouseButtonDown`. But Nothing happens to the cube after that. no errors or warnings.[image]

Comment: try Mesh Renderer instead of Renderer

Comment: @Jaimin the `MeshRenderer` **is** a `Renderer` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use a `bool` flag instead of checking the material reference

```c#
// Set the initial value via the Inspector 
// to decide whether this should start as brick or normal
[SerializeField] private bool isBrick;
// If possible already drag in the renderer via the Inspector
[SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

// If ever needed later let others know directly whether this is a brick
// this property allows read-only acccess
public bool IsBrick => isBrick;

private void Awake ()
{
    // As fallback get the renderer ONCE on runtime
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    // Apply the initial state
    _renderer.material = isBrick ? brick : normal;           
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Click");

        Debug.Log(isBrick ? "Brick" : "Normal");

        // Invert the bool flag
        isBrick = !isBrick;
     
        // Apply the new state
        _renderer.material = isBrick ? brick : normal;           
    }
}
```